# When insert JSON string to SQL table I only get the first record

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following json , when i am trying to extract it to sql i get only the first row can you please help.

```sql
    DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @json = '{
       "Reportno":{
          "Env":{
             "A":7140541,
             "B":179001,
             "C":"XML",
             "D":"SLSPRV",
             "F":90760,
             "G":202104,
             "H":2030,
             "I":{
                "J":20240118,
                "K":202202014,
                "L":22203,
                "M":2020103,
                "N":179001,
                "O":9200005,
                "P":{
                   "CustData":[
                      {
                         "CustCode":7295,
                         "Lines":{
                            "Barcode":13782,
                            "Qty":1,
                            "pack":"Box"
                         }
                      },
                      {
                         "CustCode":880,
                         "Lines":[
                            {
                               "Barcode":9245,
                               "Qty":2,
                               "pack":"unit"
                            },
                            {
                               "Barcode":5536,
                               "Qty":1,
                               "pack":"unit"
                            },
                            {
                               "Barcode":46199,
                               "Qty":3,
                               "pack":"Box"
                            },
                            {
                               "Barcode":738,
                               "Qty":1,
                               "pack":"unit"
                            },
                            {
                               "Barcode":149010,
                               "Qty":5,
                               "pack":"unit"
                               }
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }'




SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Reportno.Env.I.P.CustData')
WITH (
    CustCode varchar(150) '$.CustCode',
    Barcode BIGINT '$.Lines.Barcode',
    Qty SMALLINT '$.Lines.Qty',
    pack NVARCHAR(max) '$.Lines.pack'  
);
```

this is the resulte i get

[image]

this is what i need

[image]

Thank

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2 `OPENJSON` calls. The first for your `CustData`, adn then the 2nd for the nested JSON within `Lines`:

```sql
SELECT CD.CustCode,
       L.Barcode,
       L.Qty,
       L.pack
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Reportno.Env.I.P.CustData')
     WITH (CustCode varchar(150) '$.CustCode',
           Lines nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) CD
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CD.Lines)
                 WITH(Barcode BIGINT '$.Barcode',
                      Qty SMALLINT '$.Qty',
                      pack NVARCHAR(max) '$.pack') L;
```